# Use @ComponentScan but I can't scan the desired package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image]

I have the above repo. I start the application program from ***ApiApplication*** in the ***vn.com.fecredit.los.documentservice.api directory***. I can't scan the beans in the libs/infra folder.

> When I declared in ***ApiApplication***:
>
> [image]
>
> i can't scan bean in ***infra***.

I tried again another way:

> When I declared in ***ApiApplication***: [image] I was able to scan the bean in ***infra*** but I couldn't
> scan the bean in the service ***api*** itself.

Comment: What means "I can't scan", do you get an exception?

Comment: `Consider defining a bean of type 'vn.com.fecredit.los.documentservice.api.repositories.DocumentMngtRepository' in your configuration.`
it does not understand the interface (that has marked the repository) as a bean. In spite of, they are in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `@SpringBootApplication` use slove your problem , this annotation would scan the path which is below annotated class . so  you don't need to specified the path manually .
or else , you can assign the scan package path or exclude some class explicitly like following .  In general , specified the common package prefix as basic package

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"vn.com.fecredit.los.documentservice"}, exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Additional to say that if the spring could not found some dependency that cause inject failed , the root issue may be that you missed the `@Service` above your subclass which you defined some interface

Answer (score 0):

@hungtv Check the following

settings.gradle

```
include 'apps:api', 'libs:core', 'libs:infra' , 'apps:job-worker' , 'apps:mgmt-api', 'apps:projector'
```

apps/api/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':libs:infra')
}
```

Refer [Declaring Dependencies between Subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html)